# Trying to add an element to front of doubly-linked list ocaml

Tags: linked-list, ocaml, doubly-linked-list

I am trying to add an element to the front of a doubly-linked list, however, I am getting the right form for the output, but the value of the cycle node says : `{content = < cycle >}` when it should just say `< cycle >`.

```
add_head: (float * 'a) -> ('a lcell) ref -> unit
```

```ml
(* The type of linked lists. *)
type 'a llist =
| Nil
| Cons of (float * 'a) * 'a lcell * 'a lcell
and 'a lcell = ('a llist) ref

let add_head x head = 
   match !(!head) with
   |Nil -> head := !(singleton x)
   |Cons (e, prev, next) -> 
      let first = ref (Cons (x, ref Nil, ref !(!head))) in
      prev := !first;
      head := first
```

This is what the output should look like:

```
  {contents =
    Cons ((3.3, "c"), {contents = Nil},
     {contents =
       Cons ((1.2, "b"), <cycle>,
        {contents = Cons ((2.2, "a"),<cycle>, {contents = Nil})})})}}
```

This is my output:

```
  {contents =
    Cons ((3.3, "c"), {contents = Nil},
     {contents =
       Cons ((1.2, "b"), {contents =<cycle>},
        {contents = Cons ((2.2, "a"), {contents =<cycle>}, {contents = Nil})})})}}
```

Any help with why this is happening, and what I am not understanding ?

Comment: What does your type look like? Where is your code to add an element? What have you tried that gives the above data?

Comment: Please don't vandalize your own question. If you don't want your code here, you shouldn't have posted it in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

When you write

```
      let first = ref (Cons (x, ref Nil, ref !(!head))) in
```

you are creating a fresh reference for first, which cannot thus appears later in the list.
Then, when you update `prev` with

```
      prev := !first;
```

you are making `prev` point to the content of the new reference. Consequently,
`prev` points to a cycle but it is not part of a cycle.

In you want to avoid this indirection, you need to reuse the already existing `prev` reference rather than create a new fresh one:

```
let add_head x head = 
   match !(!head) with
   | Nil -> head := !(singleton x)
   | Cons (e, prev, next) -> 
      let first = Cons (x, ref Nil, !head) in
      prev := first;
      head := prev;;
```

Then you should get:

```
# let r= ref (ref Nil);;
# add_head (0., 0) r;;
# add_head (1., 1) r;;
# add_head (2., 2) r;;
# !r;;
{contents =
  Cons ((2., 2), {contents = Nil},
   {contents =
     Cons ((1., 1), <cycle>,
      {contents = Cons ((0., 0), <cycle>, {contents = Nil})})})}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my take on the problem.

In your function, `head` is a reference to a cell. The function should be updating the cell, not the reference to the cell. So when you assign to the head you want to do this:

```
!head := <new value>
```

Not this:

```
head := ref (<new value>)
```

I wrote some code that follows this pattern, and it gets the answer that you say is correct.

(This is exactly the same as getting the number of `*` dereferences right in C. Which is one reason why functional code is so much more pleasant :-)

Comment: Hi Jeffrey, I made the change you said to make to the final line of my code, but now i get a type error. So I tried to fix it by doing !head := !first, but this gave me the same answer as before. Would you be able to elaborate more on the change you made? Thanks